# Adding additional constraints to Laravel Eloquent relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three tables :

```
Users
(id / username)

Folders
(id / name)

Folders_settings
(folder_id / user_id / order)
```

I want to be able to select a user's folder order.

In the folder model I have :

```
//Folder Eloquent model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('user')
}
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne('FolderSettings');
}
```

I need to add a user_id constraint to the settings relation in the hasOne relation. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need the user's folder's order?

- You want the **folders_settings** table to link a **user** to a **folder**.

**Tables**

***users*** - id, username

***folders*** - id, name

**folders_settings** - id, folder_id, user_id, order

- Notice my tables start with a lowercase letter and also, there is a new field in the last table.

**Models**

```
    <?php

class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function foldersetting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Foldersetting');
    }

}


class Foldersetting extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'folders_settings';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function folder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Folder');
    }
}


class Folder extends Eloquent 
{
    public function foldersetting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Foldersetting');
    }
}
```

**Select a User's Folder Order**

```
$user = User::with('foldersetting')->find($id);
var_dump($user->foldersetting->order);
```

***That should do the trick. PS: not tested, so let me know of (if) issues.***

Answer (score 1):

This is done automatically by setting up the relation in the Users model.

```
// Inside User.php
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('FolderSettings');
}

// Inside FolderSettings.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

This should pick up the user_id field as the relation. You'd then be able to get the folders (through settings) for a specific user as follows:

```
User::with('settings.folders')->find(1);
```